# What type of encoding with Bandicam?

Tags: video-conversion, video-editing

I using Bandicam for screen recording file is so small. What type of encoding? I want to edit product from Bandicam and save, after that file is growing 8x from 10MB to 85MB.

10 MB including audio track -> 85 MB without audio track.

Have any product can be convert or edit video and saving file is small size same Bandicam?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bandicam provide a [helpful page](http://www.bandicam.com/support/tips/best-codec/) for deciding this.

As you can see on their site, they would recommend using `External: Xvid` for the smallest video option, with `MPEG-1 L2` for the audio codec.

Of course, there's a number of other things that could be in place. Check what the original codec is, and that you're not trying to increase the bitrate or resolution.

Comment: Thank you, I use Freemake video converter is allow minimum size only 33MB. I change to other converter tools file size is  5MB.